# Template URL is wrong for the templateCache in Angularjs using gulp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gulp, angular-templatecache

[image]The template URL loaded after the Gulp build is wrong. i expect the template URL should be $templateCache.put('scripts/app/cinemasList/cinemasList.html') but the actual is $templateCache.put('scripts/cinemasList/cinemasList.html')

```
gulp.task('ngtemplate', function() {
 return gulp.src(config.srcTemplates)

.pipe($.minifyHtml({
  empty: true,
  spare: true,
  quotes: true
}))
.pipe($.ngHtml2js({
  template: "    $templateCache.put('<%= template.url %>',\n        '<%= template.prettyEscapedContent %>');",
  prefix: 'scripts/'
}))
.pipe($.concat('templates.js'))
.pipe($.tap(function(file, t) {
  file.contents = Buffer.concat([
    new Buffer("(function(module) {\n" +
      "try {\n" +
      "  module = angular.module('myApp');\n" +
      "} catch (e) {\n" +
     // "  module = angular.module('myApp', []);\n" +
      "}\n" +
      "module.run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {\n"),
    file.contents,
    new Buffer("\n}]);\n" +
      "})();\n")
  ]);
}))


.pipe(gulp.dest(config.scripts + 'templates'));
```

});

Comment: Can you share the directory structure for your app?

Comment: Hi i have added the screen shot. on that my html comes under the app folder and template will be in template folder

Comment: Could you show the directory structure for the `app` directory? Where is the `gulpfile` located?

Comment: gulpfile is located in the immediate outside of the www directory..

Comment: I guest the script will move into app folder while run your task. You can try put prefix: 'scripts/app'